# react native router flux perform save function when header back button is pressed

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I've found a way to do this when you launch the Action Page, e.g. Actions.Home({onBack: () => console.log('custom back callback') }); however I do not think this will work for me. Here is a screen mockup for how the client wants the app to be done: [image] where the back button will work as a save button for the data entry page.

I do not believe I can pass in a function when I launch the page that will be able to process the data that they entered.

What I need is to process the data and save it, then continue on to go back to the previous page, or if the data is not valid then I want to say "Stay and make changes, or leave without saving?".

How can I provide that onBack function once I land on the page and have access to the fields they will be working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the (Or at least **a**) way to do it. In componentDidMount, you want to refresh the page and supply your onBack function now that you have access to it:

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        Actions.refresh({onBack:()=>this.onBack()})
    });
}
```

EDIT:
Google brought me back here (insert Thanos meme if you like) after updating RNRF to 4.1.0-beta.8 and found that the above code did not seem to execute. The fix was to import InteractionManager from react-native and wrap it around the old code like so:

```
componentDidMount() {

        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(()=> {
            Actions.refresh({onBack:()=>{
                this.props.handleReturnedImage({ uri: this.state.uri });
                Actions.pop();
            }});
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the render() method, you can add a navigation bar which contains back button and when that back button is clicked a 'onTap()' function is called, then you can write whatever you want in the onTap() function. To go back, you can use Actions.pop() method.

So you can do like if data is processed Actions.pop() else do something else.